# Why did the Ottomans rebuild Byzantine gates to a smaller format?

Tags: byzantine-empire, ottoman-empire

It's very perplexing to me. Here are some examples:

https://pages.pomona.edu/~sg064747/travel/images/Turkey/Fortifications/1600-LandWallsArchGate.jpg

https://romeonrome.com/files/2013/09/66.EmperorsGoldenGate-600x450.jpg

https://pages.pomona.edu/~sg064747/travel/images/Turkey/Fortifications/1024-YedikuleGoldenGate.jpg

http://romeartlover.tripod.com/2a.jpg

http://www.livius.org/site/assets/files/21526/thumbnail_istanbul_wall_theodosius_02_ab.jpg

https://media-cdn.tripadvisor.com/media/photo-s/0a/0f/da/40/walls-of-constantinople.jpg

One theory I heard about is that it's due to cultural differences between the conquerors and the conquered.

Comment: It would improve the question if you could provide locations for the gates shown, and possibly time frames for when the openings were closed in.

Comment: Lots of false assumptions being made here. Three of the pictures are the Golden Gate, which was walled up in the late Byzantine period (i.e. not by the Ottomans) to create a citadel. The last one doesn't look like it's been reduced to me. Not that I would call walling a gate up "rebuilding", mind you. None of these images are "examples".if there's no evidence it was "rebuilt to a smaller format" by the Ottomans.

Comment: @Semaphore it's a question, sir. If I am wrong about my assumption, instruct me about it, please.

Comment: I just did - see my comment above. If you have no evidence to support your premise that this is a systematic policy by the Ottoman Empire, I suggest you simply pick a specific gate and ask what happened to it. That way you don't randomly assume an actor or a time period.

Comment: Maybe someone else will come up and provide some insight. My argument is: if an empire occupies an area for 500 years and the original gate was larger, the conquering empire is probably responsible for the change.

Comment: @user1095108 That's a dubious assumption, not an argument. There's no law of nature forbidding the Byzantine Empire from walling in their own gates. This is why I suggest you pick a specific gate to ask about, because as it is you might as well be asking for a survey of the Near East.

Comment: This page on the [Golden Gate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Walls_of_Constantinople#Golden_Gate) indicates it was walled up **before** Constantinople fell to the Ottomons..."With the progressive decline in Byzantium's military fortunes, the gates were walled up and reduced in size in the later Palaiologan period, and the complex converted into a citadel and refuge."

Comment: yes, I've read about the late Constantinople being more a village than a city.  I was hoping to see, if a generic answer existed like the one offered by justCal. It's so pervasive in the Middle east, which was generally under Ottoman rule. I hoped someone had insights into this phenomenon.

Comment: And how about this: "It lost its function as a gate, and for much of the Ottoman era, it was used as a treasury, archive, and state prison."

Answer (score 4):

Out of the list of images in the question, some can be found on [this](https://pages.pomona.edu/~sg064747/travel/Turkey_Istanbul_Fortifications.html) site, which provides some descriptions of the photos. One of these is identified as the 'Golden Gate' of (then) Constantinople.  The Wikipedia entry says this about the [Golden Gate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Walls_of_Constantinople#Golden_Gate):

> It was the main ceremonial entrance into the capital, used especially
>   for the occasions of a triumphal entry of an emperor into the capital
>   on the occasion of military victories or other state occasions such as
>   coronations.

These military victories became much fewer, and finally:

> With the progressive decline in Byzantium's military fortunes, the
>   gates were walled up and reduced in size in the later Palaiologan
>   period, and the complex converted into a citadel and refuge.

The [Palaiologan period](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byzantine_Empire_under_the_Palaiologos_dynasty) was the last period of Byzantine rule, so the premise of the question is off. The gates were actually walled in *by the Byzantines* as a defensive measure at a time when Constantinople was more often the target of attack.  The Ottomans did *not* close this gate in.

Comment: you neglected "It lost its function as a gate, and for much of the Ottoman era, it was used as a treasury, archive, and state prison." from the same article.

Comment: But this is just one example of Byzantine architecture repurposed.

Comment: That just reflects  the gate areas usage under the Ottomans, not who did the changes you asked about in the question.

Comment: I'll wait if someone else offers other insights :) Thank you.